# Does the RPi Zero suffer performance issues with cellular modems?

Tags: pi-zero, internet, modem

Sixfab's [Raspberry Pi 4G/LTE Cellular Modem Kit](https://sixfab.com/product/raspberry-pi-4g-lte-modem-kit/) claims that it works with every 40-pin Pi:

> Fully compatible with Raspberry Pi models that have the 40-pin GPIO header (4, 3, 2, A+). **Raspberry Pi Zero may lack performance.**

I have seen similar products which also claim compatibility with "any 40-pin header Pi," but this is the only one with a warning about the Pi Zero. I have not been able to find any resource online which better describes exactly what they mean. My question is:

1. **What are the performance issues with the Pi Zero and this module? Does it take lots of power or CPU time? Is the CPU not able to meet timing requirements? etc**
2. **Though I haven't seen this warning on similar products, should I expect to see issues?**

Comment: Surely you must ask the question of the vendor?  They are making the statement.

Comment: You might ask what the vendor thinks about A+ - which has identical processor & memory to Zero